# Show labels for datetime form fields in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony2.1 (beta). I can't find a way to display labels for `datetime` fields in forms.

In the [reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html) there is no trace of a `label` property. How can it be?!

Comment: If you're using symfony 2.1, be sure to read the master doc : http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/datetime.html

Comment: Yes, thank you. By the way there is no trace of labels neither in master doc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I use it every time and works like a charm. Maybe docs bug?

```
$builder->add('creation_date', 'date', array(
    'label' => 'Creation date',
));
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. No way. By the way I noticed this issue with `datetime` fields, I didn't try `date` fields.

Comment: Setting the "label" option is the correct approach. Do you render your form manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can show the label of a field "myDate" for example like this:

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.myDate, 'Choose a date: (this is the label sentence)') }}
</div>
```

(Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

You can also personalize your form render: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: I'm printing the whole form with `{{ form_widget(form) }}`. I would avoid to manually print every field for this "bug".

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Symfony 2.7
I fixed this way:

```
    ->add('issuedAt', 'date', array( 'label_render' => true,
        'show_child_legend' => false,
        'label' => 'Issued at date:',
            ...
```